# How to get an attribute of element by jquery

Tags: jquery, chart.js, attr

I have a Html pie chart like this:

```
    //In Html:
    <canvas id="pieChart" data="12,12,12,4"></canvas>

    //In js: 
    //pie chart
    var ctx = document.getElementById("pieChart");
    ctx.height = 300;
    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'pie',
        data: {
            datasets: [{
                //data: $(this).attr("data").split(","), //This is what I want to do.
                data: [45, 25, 20, 10], //This is the original code.
                backgroundColor: [
                    "rgba(0, 123, 255,0.9)",
                    "rgba(0, 123, 255,0.7)",
                    "rgba(0, 123, 255,0.5)",
                    "rgba(0,0,0,0.07)"
                ],
                hoverBackgroundColor: [
                    "rgba(0, 123, 255,0.9)",
                    "rgba(0, 123, 255,0.7)",
                    "rgba(0, 123, 255,0.5)",
                "rgba(0,0,0,0.07)"
                ]

            }],
            labels: [
                "green",
                "green",
                "green"
            ]
        },
        options: {
            responsive: true
        }
    });
```

the code $(this).attr("data").split(",") raise an error says :

```
    Cannot read property 'split' of undefined
```

So, how can I get the value of "data"?
Thanks.

---

The answer is ctx.getAttribute('data').
Thanks for your guys :)

Comment: What is `this`?  jQuery is intended to be used with DOM Elements.  If what you are giving jQuery is not an Element, it's not going to know what to do.  `attr()` is just a wrapper for `getAttribute()` off of an Element.

Comment: Since you already have the element `ctx.getAttribute("data")`

Comment: I don't think an array has a split function

Comment: can you please explain more what you exactly want, so i will able to understand and try to solve?

Comment: Thank you guys. Just a stupid mistake...I copied code from another function where "this" is the ctx~~~~ 3 years since the last time I touched JS @_@

Comment: And thanks for @Taplar and others ( can only @ one user once, sorry)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't use `this`, it returns an error because it refers to the `Chart`, not the HTML node.

As you already have the `ctx` variable targeting the node, I suggest you to use it. Then, there are 2 possibilities:

- Using `.getAttribute(…)` on your `ctx` element in native JavaScript (you don't *need* jQuery),
- Or using `$(ctx).attr(…)` if you prefer using jQuery.

**Snippet**

```js
//pie chart
var ctx = document.getElementById("pieChart");
ctx.height = 300;
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'pie',
  data: {
    datasets: [{
      data: ctx.getAttribute("data").split(","), // Here is how you can do it without jQuery !…
      // data: $(ctx).attr("data").split(","),   // … And with jQuery !
      backgroundColor: [
        "rgba(0, 123, 255,0.9)",
        "rgba(0, 123, 255,0.7)",
        "rgba(0, 123, 255,0.5)",
        "rgba(0,0,0,0.07)"
      ],
      hoverBackgroundColor: [
        "rgba(0, 123, 255,0.9)",
        "rgba(0, 123, 255,0.7)",
        "rgba(0, 123, 255,0.5)",
        "rgba(0,0,0,0.07)"
      ]

    }],
    labels: [
      "green",
      "green",
      "green"
    ]
  },
  options: {
    responsive: true
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.2/Chart.bundle.js"></script>
<canvas id="pieChart" data="12,12,12,4"></canvas>
```

Comment: Your answer is absolutely right! Thanks for your guys.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should use the `data-*` syntax.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes

Secound:

I would say `ctx.getAttribute('data')` would be your fix?

But please change the `data` attribute to something else. (data-set....) :)

Comment: `$(this)` referes to the `new Chart` not the html node.